# Octonion Algebras Over Number Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions, octonions

Is there any textbook or paper about Arithmetic of Octonion Algebras or Octonion Algebras constructed over number fields?
I know [J. Voight](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/quat-book.pdf) book and [K. Martin](http://www2.math.ou.edu/~kmartin/quaint/ch6.pdf) notes about quaternion algebras but I was thinking about a generalization using Octonions.

More than that: Is it possible to define Orders and Maximal Orders over an octonion algebra? Or these concepts just make sense over associative algebras?

Comment: The answer to the second question is yes. For example, there is just one octonion division algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$, and it has a unique [maximal order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#Integral_octonions) up to isomorphism, related to the famous $E_8$ lattice. Not surprisingly, John Baez has written about it, see [here](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/integers/).

Comment: @pregunton but if we choose, for example, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Can we construct an octonion algebra over this field as we can do in the quaternionic case?

Comment: I don't remember the exact details, but I think that over a number field with $r$ embeddings into $\mathbb{R}$ there are $2^r$ octonion algebras, one is the usual [split octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-octonion) and the others are division. In the case of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ there are two real embeddings, so there should be four octonion algebras in total.

Answer (score 3):

I actually have a mostly written chapter on Octonions in my personal version of my quaternion algebra notes, which I might finish up and post if I ever teach that course or start thinking about these things again.

Anyway, there are far fewer octonion algebras than quaternion algebras, as mentioned in @pregunton's comment.  Basically at a finite place you only have a local split octonion algebra and over a real place you can have the split or non-split one, leading to $2^r$ octonion algebras over a number field with $r$ real places.  This is in the beginning of Springer and Veldkamp's book.  You could also check some books on composition algebras.

You also have a notion of orders and maximal orders.  For facts about the usual octonions $\mathbb O$ over $\mathbb Q$, see Conway and Sloane's book and Baez's Bulletin article.  The former talks about various orders and factorization problems, the latter of which have since been studied in a few "meta-commutation" articles.  van der Blij and Springer (1959) show all maximal orders of $\mathbb O$ (and as I recall any definite octonion algebra) are isomorphic.  Susanna Epp in the 70's also studied orders in octonion algebras (look for the term "Cayley algebra").

Comment: Thank you for your response! I look forward to reading your notes when they come to be published.

One more question: when $ \mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2}) $, is it possible to say that there is an order or a maximum order? Or, can the "integral structures" in quaternion algebra over a numeric field be generalized to octonion algebras over a numeric field?

Comment: Yes, the above references should tell you some basic things about orders and maximal orders over arbitrary number fields.  You can also use Cayley-Dickson doubling to construct orders in octonion algebras from ones in quaternion algebras, but you won't directly get maximal orders (I think) this way.